# Quickly formatting multi-word sections of Markdown text in Sublime Text 3

Tags: markdown, code-snippets, sublimetext3

So I’m using Markdown in Sublime Text 3 to try to quickly transcribe a podcast I quite like, and I’m using a specific notation for “stage direction”-like bits to indicate laughter, or singing, or sighing, or what-have-you. I do this thusly:

`**\*crosstalk, person laughs\***`

Obviously, this makes it appear as “***crosstalk, person laughs***” when the Markdown is rendered as rich text. The problem is that because I do this relatively frequently, I want to create a snippet or something that will cut down on the time it takes to type this rather unwieldy thing. I’d like to either:

1. Hit a hotkey (or do a tab-complete) that will automatically place the opening `**\*` and closing `\***`, with the cursor in-between the two so I can type the direction I want, OR:
2. Hit a hotkey (or do a tab-complete) that will invoke a “mode” or input box of some sort where I can simply type the desired text, hit Enter, and it will then place the opening and closing characters as appropriate, and place my cursor after the whole shebang so I can keep typing.

I’ve made one tab-complete snippet so far that was much less involved, but I’m a Sublime Text neophyte so this is punching a bit above my weight.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after a night’s sleep and another look at the unofficial documentation. Somehow I missed the spot where you could use $1, $2, etc. to define tab “stops” within the snippet. Simply set up a snippet whose content was `**\*$1\***`, which let me type the trigger, hit tab, type the stage direction, and hit tab again to keep going.